# Atom: Which module need to see changed line between versions?

Tags: atom-editor

I am looking for the same view when I look at the chaged lines between version. Is it possible with Atom?

And I can edit the left panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Atom package [git-time-machine](https://github.com/littlebee/git-time-machine)

Comment: git-time-machine is quite ugly and useless compare to Xcode, but theoretically it offers the same.